# How do I remove a Chrome Foxtab speed dial?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I've added several sites to the Chrome extension [Foxtab Speed Dial](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/foxtab-speed-dial/fcoecifcadmambfikillppkoafmgachp). However I can't figure out how to remove a speed dial thumbnail!

Comment: rightclick on thumbnail-->remove nail doesn't it work?

Comment: @Vignesh4303 - Right-clicking just gives the standard browser menu (reload ... inspect element).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Click on the edit icon on the top right corner:

   [image]
2. Click the cross on the top right corner of the tile you want to remove:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks - I'd tried that but the overlays are subtle enough on my laptop that I didn't see the cross!